# SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in target list

Tags: sql

I have done this SQL request :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
*, j_start_date, typeNP.j_value, g_challenge.j_title
FROM g_challenge 
INNER JOIN g_challenge_catset typeNP ON g_challenge.j_row_id = typeNP.j_item_id AND typeNP.j_value IN  ('jbm_5233','jbm_5232','bfr_8227')
INNER JOIN g_challenge_catset as tps ON g_challenge.j_row_id = tps.j_item_id AND tps.j_value IN  ('aga_7777','aga_7778','aga_7776')
LEFT OUTER JOIN g_dbsocialgroup gdb ON g_challenge.j_dbsocialgroup_id = gdb.j_row_id || '_DBSocialGroup'
WHERE (j_start_date >= '2018-08-13' OR (j_start_date <= '2018-08-13' AND j_end_date >= '2018-08-13')) AND  g_challenge.j_pstatus = 0 AND g_challenge.j_mutualiste_type = false 
ORDER BY 
CASE typeNP.j_value
    WHEN 'bfr_8227' THEN '1' 
    WHEN 'jbm_5233' THEN '2' 
    WHEN 'jbm_5232' THEN '3'
    END,
j_start_date ASC, g_challenge.j_title ASC
```

But I got this error : SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in target list and I don't know why ?

Help me please

Comment: Your code is quite confused.  The `*` should be selecting the additional columns.  Sample data and desired results are always helpful.

Comment: The error message is quite clear, when SELECT DISTINCT, only select list items may be specified in the ORDER BY clause!

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: what is CASE really doing? Order By 1 or 2 or 3 ??

Comment: For the column typeNp.j_value I want the 'bfr_8227' first and then 'jbm_5233', and then 'jbm_5232'. If i remove the 'DISTINCT' the request works

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved this with a group by

```
GROUP BY g_challenge.j_start_date, typeNP.j_value, g_challenge.j_title, g_challenge.j_row_id, typeNP.j_item_id, tps.j_item_id, tps.j_value, gdb.j_row_id
```

and with removing the DISTINCT and named columns in the select